# Cute Editor Replacement

Tags: asp.net, editor

I am building an asp.net site in which I need to have editor text boxes in different forms.
I am planning to buy cute editor license but just want to check whether there are any alternatives available in open source.

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there are

- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is open source under LGPL.